# Java RGB code to csv - table aggregation

Tags: java, csv, pixel, indexoutofboundsexception

I  have prepared the code for reading the R G and B value from each pixel that I want (each pixel in each 10 row of the picture). It returns me the position of pixel and its respective RGB values but in columns only. Now I have to go deeper into this and I would like the program to give me also a CSV file with such aggregation of the table: first column will be the y position on the tested picture, first row the x position (pixel by pixel), next row is R value, then G, then B. The thing is that I have put it into the loop for it to be done automatically but I have stacked again - ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException what I think I shouldn't have. Here is the code:

```
PrintWriter output;
Table Tabela;
String i;
void setup()

{
 output = createWriter("positions.txt");     //writedown tool enter
 Tabela=new Table();
  size(251,201);                             // screen size setup
  PImage img = loadImage("sharp.jpg");       // implementing image Sketch->Add File
  image(img,0,0);                            // placeing the img on the screen
  loadPixels();                              // work on pixels

  for(int s=0; s < pixels.length; s=s+9*width)    // go through selected rows of pixels with intervals of 10 rows (0 to 0+9width)
  {
    for(int j=0; j < width; j++)               // go through each pixel in selected row
    {
    float r=red(pixels[s+j]);                  // read the red value from each chceked pixel
    float b=blue(pixels[s+j]);                 // read the blue value from each chceked pixel
    float g=green(pixels[j+s]);                // read the green value from each checked pixel

   Tabela.addColumn("Y");
   String i=Integer.toString(j);
   Tabela.addColumn(i);
   TableRow newRow=Tabela.addRow();
   newRow.setInt("Y", Tabela.lastRowIndex());

   newRow.setFloat(s,r);
   newRow.setFloat(s,g);
   newRow.setFloat(s,b);

   output.println(s + " , "+ j +" , "+ r + " , " + g + " , " + b);  //write the data down to the file (selected data)

   color black = color(0, 0, 0);                              // checking, set a black color
   pixels[j+s]=black;                                         // checking, change the color of current pixel

  println(s + " , "+ j +" ; "+ r + " , " + g + " , " + b);    // print the read data

    }
    }
    output.flush();
    saveTable(Tabela,"data/tabela.csv");
    updatePixels();                                // set changes
}

void keyPressed()
{
output.flush();  // Writes the remaining data to the file
 output.close();  // Finishes the file
  exit();  // Stops the program
}
```

I would like to get something like this:

```
rowIndex0 ; redValue , greenValue, blueValue ; redValue , greenValue, blueValue ...
rowIndex1 ; redValue , greenValue, blueValue ; redValue , greenValue, blueValue ...
```

With semicolons I have divided the pixels in one row just to show what's my idea. The columns will be same for each row (e.g. 0 pixel in each row). And about separating the columns just after loadPixels() - this will only set up first column, isn't it? What about the "i" columns that will refer to the pixel in row? How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

given your comment, you should correct the for statement to jump on a multiple of 10: e.g.

```
for(int s=0; s < pixels.length; s=s+10*width)
```

Warning: You are creating using the following lines for each pixel 2 new columns! you should move the lines in a separate for just after loadPixels().

```
for(int j=0; j < width; j++) {
  Tabela.addColumn("Y");
  String i=Integer.toString(j);
  Tabela.addColumn(i);
}
```

As for the original question, please be clear which format you need. Is this your desired format?

```
rowIndex , columnIndex , redValue , greenValue , blueValue
```